# React, axios, content-type

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I have already searched a lot, but none of the solutions found work: Cannot send content-type by axios. but if I use the postman interceptor and I 'send' the request generated by axios this time it works: the node.js / express server correctly receives the request and body-parser works normally!

React side:

```
const API_URL = "http://localhost:8800/auth/";

const headers = {
  accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
  'content-type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8'
};

class AuthService {
  register(pseudo, email, password) {
    return axios.post(API_URL + "signup/",
      { pseudo, email, password },
      { headers: headers})
    .then(response => {
      if (response.data.accessToken) {
        localStorage.setItem("user", JSON.stringify(response.data));
      }
      return response.data;
    });
  }
```

server side

```
const app = express();
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    console.log( req.headers);
    next();
}); 
app.use( bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }), bodyParser.json());
```

Comment: English, please.

Comment: Try using CORS middleware

Comment: @DimitarVeljanovski — That absolutely won't help. CORS permission is required to (a) Set the content-type header (which is what the question is about) and (b) read the response (which the code in the question is doing).

Comment: "Cannot send content-type by axios" — I tested that code, and the content-type is set correctly (not that it needs to be, JSON is the default for Axios). I can't reproduce the problem. Check the browser's Console for error messages.

Comment: for Quentin : I just add `app.use(cors());` after `const app = express();`, no other change and it's ok

Comment: for Quentin : I try `axios.defaults.responseType = 'json';` just before `axios.post` but always not working.

Answer (score -1):

Usually when I use axios I send the headers in a config variable like this and I stringify the body so it sends as JSON object and not a JS object.

```
const config = {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
    };

    const body = JSON.stringify({arguments});
    try {
      const res = await axios.post(/url, body, config);

...
```

Here's a link to the docs for a little more reading about it:

https://github.com/axios/axios

Comment: The real reason his request is getting blocked is probably CORS. This will work for sending text, but if you try to send files (which you cant simply jsonify), you will get the error again.

Comment: I try your solution (without cors) and it doesn't work